# Wordpress Contact Form 7 Conditional Redirect

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I wish to redirect users to a page depending on the dropdown option they have selected.

Example: If they select Option A from dropdown menu, they are redirected to Page A. If they select Option B, they are redirected to Page B.

All pages will belong to the same domain name.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple JS script for that:

```js
var option = document.getElementById('options');
option.addEventListener('change', () => window.location.href = option.value);
```

```html
<select id="options">
<option></option>
  <option value="https://stackoverflow.com">A</option>
  <option value="http://google.com">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Reza, this JS script is not working. Can you please confirm where exactly should i put this. Also option tag has nothing inside it, so should i remove that?

Comment: `[select* your-project class:form-control first_as_label "Select" "Option A|hello@hello.com" "Option B|sales@hello.com"]`
this is what i currently have

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. I put this in functions.php file.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   console.log(event.detail);   
   if ( '2028' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
        console.log(event.detail.inputs[5].value);
        if (event.detail.inputs[5].value == '2021') {
           location = 'https://example.com/wp- 
           content/uploads/Brochure-2021.pdf';
        }
        if (event.detail.inputs[5].value == '2020') {
           location = 'https://example.com/wp- 
           content/uploads/Brochure-2020.pdf';
        }
    } 
   }, false );
   </script>
```